# Return argument C#

Tags: c#, return

I wanted to know if it okay to write this kind of method in C# :

```
public static string foo(string myString){
    myString = Regex.Replace(somecode);
    return myString;
}
```

And somewhere else do :

```
myString => foo(myString)
```

I am a C user (and C++ but new one) and I think this is very awkward to return an argument passed to the function. With that the program works perfectly but it is bug free ? I tried to look it up online but couldn't find anything relevant.

Thank you for you help !

Comment: You can return function arguments in C/C++ too

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are truly asking.  In the method you show you are not doing anything with the argument and the method could just as easily be written as a method that takes no parameter and just returns the result of the Regex manipulation that is presumably being done on some global static value.

Comment: @pstrjds I think the OP means `Regex.Replace(myString, somecode)`

Comment: @vc74 - I bet you are correct, I didn't think about that `Regex.Replace` is the static method that takes a couple of arguments, rather than being a regex object that has been created with a pattern and then is being used in other places.

Comment: This method is a complete waste of printable characters. Disregarding what the inner method actually does, as it stands all this is a pointless wrapper. Just call `somecode = Regex.Replace(somecode)` when you need to, and forget the wrapper all together

Comment: Danny, you could be a little clearer about what is actually itching you here. Also it doesn't help that the RegEx call isn't valid.

Comment: @TheGeneral - the code is incomplete. There are at least a pattern and a replacement value being encapsulated.

Comment: Hey, actually I just wanted to know if I could, and I now I know I do ^^ It was just weird in my head to do that, I learned at school that I shouldn't.

Comment: And it was just a sample code, the real function is far more complicated, I am just not allowed to share it here. And yes about Regex.Replace, I just didn't see the point about completing the arguments, since it returns anyway a string, and since I'm lazy hahah. Anyway thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to know if it okay

It is valid and it will work correctly.

At the same time, re-using the parameter is considered a bad practice.  Introducing an extra variable costs absolutely nothing and aids in readability:

```
public static string foo(string myString)
{
    string result = Regex.Replace(somecode, ...);
    return result;
}
```

And it is also ok to write `foo` in the same lambda style you are using it in:

```
public static string foo(string myString) => Regex.Replace(somecode, myString, ...);
```

Comment: You don't even need `string result`... just return the `Regex.Replace(...)` directly.

Comment: @Nyerguds - did you see that last line in the answer?

Comment: _"It is valid and it will work correctly.....I did. Nothing conclusive there"_ - it won't compile.  Neither will your code sadly

Comment: No, `...` usually doesn't compile. I don't see what other problems you've got. Be more explicit.

Comment: @User453465436754 - OPs code won't compile and @boomelding added the `...` to indicate that there are other parameters required, but since OP did not provide those parameters it is anyone's guess as to what they should be.

Comment: @pstrjds What's the point of `mystring`? It is never used as others have said.  What is `somecode`?  What is `...`?  What's the point of the method? It's rather _"pointless"_ as others have said.  OPs question is subject to more interpretation than a Ridley Scott film

Comment: @User453465436754 - I agree on the pointlessness (see my much earlier comment on the question asking for some kind of clarification), and @bommelding's answer, IMHO, makes a decent effort at trying to interpret and answer the question and added the `...` to indicate something is missing.  The statement that "It is valid and it will work correctly" is true, in the sense that IF the OP has compiling code (not what is in the question), it will work correctly in the sense that the argument passed in will not be modified from the callers perspective and will return a modified string.

Answer (score 1):

While you can, you don't necessarily need to. In this case, you don't need to change the value of the argument at all, you can simply:

```
return Regex.Replace(somecode);
```

This is okay to do, because you're passing the value of `myString` into your argument, and not a reference to the string itself, though it is possible to do this by using the [`ref` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) in your parameter declarations.

Comment: Yes I know ^^ It is just the skeleton of the actual function ;)

Comment: No worries, but otherwise yeah, go ahead and return that parameter! It won't have any bearing on the argument object, unless you use the `ref` keyword pass a reference to that object :)

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning a normal parameter like you did here doesn't do anything to the argument passed in, because the reference of the `string` is passed as value into the method, so it's fine to do this.

This means that you can just write:

```
public static string foo(string myString){
    return Regex.Replace(somecode);
}
```

to achieve the exact same thing.

I would say that modifying a parameter is ok, you just have to beware that it actually does not change the argument passed in.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is okay, as you are manipulating your parameter and then you return. Functions are mainly written for this, to do something based on the input (the parameters) or to manipulate the parameters in someway (just as you did)